# Android Studio- Databases

Tags: java, database, algorithm, android-studio-3.0

I'm currently working a "Street Safe" app that will list certain areas in a community as dangerous through the location sensor. In addition to this, it will give recent crime updates in neighboring areas. My only problem is that I don't know how to achieve this, I know I will have to implement Google Maps but how will I be able to make a program that displays recent crime alerts? Are there certain public police databases that can be imported into Android Studio or how will I be able to achieve this? Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Well it depends on where do you live ...

Your best shot is to research if there is an API made by your state police but the chances are small considering this type of data ...

You won't access any precise crime databases as it's "government based".

**EDIT :**

after some research i came across this : [Crime Report API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22070492/crime-report-api)

you should also check https://www.programmableweb.com/category/crime/apis?category=20160
if there's one that suits your localization ... but again it may not be very precise and up to date data.

Comment: following this question.

Answer (score -1):

You should look for other apps that have the stadistics of the crime alters and ask if they can share with you. That will be easier than asking the goverment to give you that data.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).